# Different Mail subjects based on questions

Tags: jquery, mailto

On my new website is a Question box with multiple questions – which change randomly on reload. Within a textfield, people can type in their answer and press a submit button. My goal now, is that when pressing the submit button, the mail opens with the question as the subject and their answer in the mail body.

My coding skills are limited, that's why I'm only working with HTML, CSS and Jquery. I've searched the internet, but have absolutely no idea how to code this.
You can find an example of what I mean on the bottom of this website: https://studiomut.com

That's the HTML Code so far.

```
            <div class="text_big_full_width">
            </div>

            <div id="form_contact_question">
                <label for="type">Type</label>
                <input type="text" id="form_type" name="form_contact">

                <a href="mailto:hello@corinakoch.ch?subject=Hello&body=Hello Corina,">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
```

And that's the jQuery:

```
var textToShow = ['What’s your current mood, as a drink.', 'Tell me something weird about yourself', 'What do you think is overrated? And what is underrated?', 'If you had to give your car a name, what would you call it?', 'Who should aliens talk to first when they land on Earth?', 'Complete this sentence: I just won the lottery! If you are looking for me tomorrow, I will be ___.', 'Dishes inside or outside the sink?']
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".text_big_full_width").html(textToShow[Math.floor(Math.random()*textToShow.length)]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't wrap a button in an anchor. Plus you have a random end div.

I cleaned up your code. And I'm making the random question a variable on load. Then just referring to that variable where needed.

I started making it a snippet, but the snippet must have security not allowing javascript mailto links, but JSFiddle did so I know it works.

```
var textToShow = ['What’s your current mood, as a drink.', 'Tell me something weird about yourself', 'What do you think is overrated? And what is underrated?', 'If you had to give your car a name, what would you call it?', 'Who should aliens talk to first when they land on Earth?', 'Complete this sentence: I just won the lottery! If you are looking for me tomorrow, I will be ___.', 'Dishes inside or outside the sink?']

let question = textToShow[Math.floor(Math.random() * textToShow.length)];
$(document).ready(function() {

let answer = $("#form_type");
 
  $(".text_big_full_width").html(question);
  
  $(".btnSubmit").on("click",() => {
      let query = "mailto:example@example.com?subject=" + encodeURIComponent(question) + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(answer.value)
      window.location.href = query
  });
  
});


<div class="text_big_full_width"></div>

<div id="form_contact_question">
  <label for="type">Type</label>
  <input type="text" id="form_type" name="form_contact">
  <button class="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for cleaning everything up. I'm still a newby :)
The code is almost working – but now in the body of the mail isn't the typed in answer displayed but it says undefined...